# What is the "category of bifurcations"?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics, ct.category-theory

While reading the introduction to [this paper by Curtis McMullen](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/muniv/muniv.pdf), I came to the following (bold added):

> In this paper we show that *every* bifurcation set contains a copy of the boundary of the Mandelbrot set or its degree $d$ generalization. The Mandelbrot sets $M_d$ are thus *universal*; they are **initial objects in the category of bifurcations**, providing a lower bound on the complexity of $B(f)$ for all families $f_t$.

(Here $f_t$ is a family of rational functions mapping $P^1$ to itself and depending holomorphically on a parameter $t$ ranging over some complex manifold, and the bifurcation set (or locus) $B(f)$ is the set of $t$ at which the dynamics of $f_t$ undergo a discontinuous change. For a positive integer $d\geq 2$, $M_d$ is the set of $t$ for which the function $z\mapsto z^d+t$ has a connected Julia set, and $\partial M_d$, the boundary of $M_d$, is the bifurcation locus for the family $\{z\mapsto z^d+t\}_t$.)

Even without knowing exactly what the "category of bifurcations" is, I can see an analogy between the claim about Mandelbrot sets and the concept of initial objects, but presumably something more definite is intended. My question is thus how to interpret the second sentence quoted from McMullen's paper, or more simply: what is the "category of bifurcations"?

Comment: There's something fishy here with the "or": are there supposed to be a family of nonisomorphic initial objects?

Comment: On the face of it, that seems to be what it's saying, but that would be impossible. I'm hoping the proper definition of the category will clear that up. 

Comment: It might be that rather than a single initial object, there is a "multi-initial-object": http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/multilimit .  For example, the category of fields has a multi-initial-object, namely the family of all prime fields.


Comment: I just thought of that example after I posted that comment, but I wasn't sure if it had a name.  Thanks!

Comment: of course, I ought to read the thing ( :P ) but even multilimit sounds wrong --- these things are just too flexible! I'd be inclined to believe that they're saying pieces of the M-sets are good domains for probing bifurcations, dual to how Menger sets are good codomains for maps from fractals; more than that sounds like too much.

Comment: I thought it might be saying something like: if you look at *a bifurcation*, in some precise sense I don't know how to formulate, then it's as if you're looking at one of the M-sets (in a unique way, up to ...???). Maybe we should consider neighborhoods or families of neighborhoods of bifurcation points, which is outside my zone of familiarity but sounds like the type of thing other people might have thought about.  

Comment: I'm sure that "the category of bifurcations" is a (the unique?) category whose objects are bifurcation loci, but I'm not sure what the morphisms are.  I happen to know that the bifurcation locus of the family $f_t(z) = z - p_t(z)/p'_t(z)$, where $p_t(z) = (z^2 - 1)(z - t)$, is composed of many rotated and scaled copies of $\partial M_2$, so the morphisms ought to be the sort of thing that can take $\partial M_2$ to many (I think infinitely many) scaled and rotated copies of $\partial M_2$.  From other context in the paper I think the copies must be allowed to be quasi-conformal images.